# UIImagePickerController freezes when selecting a picture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to allow users to modify their profile image. I have implemented the correct code and entered the correct call in my plist. My app crashes when I choose a picture and select "choose" I will place my code below.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class EditProfileVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
    setupProfileImageView()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}
func setupProfileImageView() {
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive=true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
}
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()
```

}
 I have also created an extension file

```
import UIKit

extension EditProfileVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
  let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = true

present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]
    as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]
    as? UIImage{
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }        
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }

    print(info)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("Canceled Picker")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String :   AnyObject])
    {
    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        profileImageView.image = img
    }
}
}
```

in my Plist, I put in privacy-photo library in usage description.

When I select my picture and press choose to update the users profile image, it crashes and sends an error message,

> ["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage":  size
>   {1122, 1125} orientation 0 scale 1.000000,
>   "UIImagePickerControllerImageURL":
>   file:///Users/zachwilcox/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C05956CC-616F-42FB-B067-110AF2BD7713/data/Containers/Data/Application/B386A454-C96D-447F-8FB2-5FFCCF1D1780/tmp/63AD5A2C-4214-4E45-9961-F800699B14E0.jpeg, "UIImagePickerControllerMediaType": public.image,
>   "UIImagePickerControllerCropRect": NSRect: {{0, 78},
>   {2456.9999065657889, 2458}}, "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL":
>   assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=0F3CDF5B-A958-45D2-822E-571323272379&ext=JPG,
>   "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage":  size
>   {3024, 3780} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]

I have no idea what this means, why its called or how to fix it. If someone can please help me understand why this happened I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have any image with "users" in your assets or project folder?

Comment: can you try removing the code, imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users") from your lazy var and try?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I do not, no. I am trying to allow users to pick from their phones.  I dragged and dropped pictures from my computer to the simulators photos.

Comment: <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your photo library</string>, I think you need to add the permission in your pList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate method. Try removing the below from your code.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String :   AnyObject])
{
if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

    profileImageView.image = img
}
}
```

**Edit**:

Dismiss imagepickercontroller after choosing an image. 
To be included at the bottom inside of the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and energy helping assist this issue. Although I am still having the same problem.. I updated my info plist and thought I made the correct changes however it’s still freezing and giving me that error

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You forgot to dismiss the imagepickercontroller after picking an image. Add this  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) inside the bottom of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

Comment: that was it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to know ;)